# Chef install package to non default location

Tags: package, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using chef resource package to install, it always get installed to the default location. Say for example, the code below will install in `/etc/httpd`

`package "httpd" do
    action :install
    end`

If I want to have it installed to a custom location, what is the way to achieve it?

Regards,
Pradip

Answer (score 2):

There is an `options` property you can use to pass command line arguments to whatever the underlying package install command, but few OSes support relocation for distro packages so this is likely to go very poorly. Assuming you are using yum, it would be

```
package "httpd" do
  options "--installroot=/path"
end
```

Comment: options "--installroot=/path" didnt work  , using zypp , Suse12

Comment: Like I said, it almost certainly won't work with normal distro packages on any major linux distro. They don't make their packages in a way that allows relocation.

Comment: Also the CLI option for Zypper would be `--root`.